# How to efficiently install same apps on 2 phones?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have a main phone and a backup phone. Main phone is functional and has a bunch of apps installed. How do I install all the same apps on the second phone while using same Google account?

Comment: Back up from first phone apps to Google backup. Factory reset second phone and set it up afresh with same account. It would prompt you to restore apps, accept that and you would have *most* if not all apps restored. Download missing apps from Play Store. All this is possible if you are talking of Marshmallow and above- please [edit] your question to mention Android versions of both devices (note that data will not be restored in all cases)

Comment: If both devices are rooted, most efficient and fool proof way would be to use Titanium Backup to restore apps with data.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer all **apk** files of apps to backup phone using any transfer app or Bluetooth. And install all that apk files in backup phone.

There is not required any internet data.

Comment: While the question doesn't say anything about root, I believe this method requires root access though since APK files are located in internal storage.